# Overlapping content on Safari iPad mini

Tags: bug, design, profile-page, safari, ipad

There seems to be an issue with overlapping content in Safari on an iPad mini 1, model `A1432`, with `iOS 9.3.5` running. Switching it off and on again, deleting cache, rebooting, etc. has not solved anything.

[image]

Comment: What version of Safari is that?

Comment: If [this](https://www.lifewire.com/check-the-version-number-of-safari-446563) is true, it's probably Safari 9 due to iOS 9.

Comment: If that's the case, you are probably out of luck. You are at least 3 major versions behind and according to this that's not supported: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I'm not sure, it's also saying _"**Mobile view** Supported: the versions that come with iOS 9 and up."_ I would classify an iPad as mobile.

Comment: *Mobile Safari **(iPhone browser)***, iPhone and iPads aren't the same format.

Comment: At least there's something Cubist about it.